# How to invert a recyclerListView like the messenger message list?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I found this link:  [Solution from owner](https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview/issues/325). But the answer is really obscure and I'm literally a noob to React native. What does this mean? Can anyone provide me with a real code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  This is not a code writing service.  It appears you already found "real code" to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! You just need to apply transform : [{scaleY : -1}] to both your RLV and your container view of each item. This should work perfectly